# How can I use custom messages with mutable specs2 specifications?

Tags: specs2

I can not seem to get specs2 to print any custom messages.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MessageSpecs extends Specification {
  "This" should {
    "fail" in {
      true.must(beFalse).setMessage("this should PRINT")
      //true.must(beFalse.setMessage("this should PRINT")) // or maybe this?  no.
      //true.must(beFalse).updateMessage(_ => "this should PRINT") // not this either
    }
  }
}
```

I simply get the default failure message "the value is true".  This is on specs2 3.8.5 using the JUnitRunner via maven.  I have not tried this on an sbt project yet.  The documentation I can find suggests that this should work.

--- Edit ---

sort-of work-around:  `true.aka("this should PRINT").must(beFalse) // works`

That prints up a bit ugly when used in practice to describe a complicated failure, but at least it prints, so I can add the additional context necessary to more easily understand the failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here comes from the fact that you are using a mutable specification. In a mutable specification exceptions are thrown when a result is incorrect. In that case, before you can even try to set a different message, the test fails (with the original message).

You have 2 options:

- set the message on the matcher itself

  ```
  false must beTrue.setMessage("ko")
  ```
- capture the result with `org.specs2.execute.AsResult` 
  (this catches exceptions)

  ```
  AsResult(false must beTrue).updateMessage("ko")
  ```

You will also notice that the API to set/update messages is slightly different depending on setting a message on a `MatchResult` (for which there is a matched entity) and a `Result` (which is a more general notion). The former uses `setMessage`, the latter uses `updateMessage`.

And, for the record, there are other ways to add more information to a given failure:

- use `aka` to describe the actual value as you noticed
- use a sentence to describe the full expectation

  ```
  "Values are correct" ==> {
    values must beCorrect
  }
  ```
- create a new matcher

  ```
  def myMatcher: Matcher[Int] = (i: Int) =>
    (test(i), s"what's wrong with $i")
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Eric .  I am fairly sure I saw this with some more complicated matchers than beFalse that led me to reduce it to the above.  If I see them again I'll put a note here.   I have since re-organized the spec, however, and am using `aka` as it seems more reliable.